# Is it risky to completely fill up a hdd with a veracrypt container?

Tags: veracrypt

I always use all my hard drives only between 75% and 80% of their capacities (after having formatting them),
I leave the rest to allow windows to properly perform maintenance on my hard drives.

I would like to create a veracrypt container of 99 GB (I do not want to encrypt the entire partition or the entire hard disk)
in a 100 GB hard drive, is it dangerous to damage my hard drive?
Will my datas be more at a risk than if i create a veracrypt container of 80 GB?

Is it risky to fill a veracrypt container to the limit of its capacity?

What are the worst mistakes to avoid with a veracrypt container?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Your question seems to have questions inside a question and borderline opinion based. Try focusing your question on one specific issue to get a more detailed responses. Head over to [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/help/asking) page to get some handy hints on how to ask the best question you can regarding your specific issue.

Comment: Why are you against using FDE?

Comment: I don't think it is risky. The 80% watermark is a filesystem management thing, as when filesystems get full they tend to fragment and take a big performance hit.  This probably does not apply as much when using a file as a block device - but you might want to defragment the drive once the file is created and avoid creating it as a sparse file.

Comment: Somehow, i am under the impression that FDE bring a higher probability of mechanical problems in the hdd, and associate the hdd with a specific hardware config (if my mobo die then i lost all my datas) ,  and with a container, i can copy the entire file to another hdd on my backup server, then (when needed) i open both container and synchronise them with freefilesync.

Comment: I agree that "as when filesystems get full they tend to fragment and take a big performance hit" .I think that i will keep on not using more than 75% to 80%, for safety and for a higher performance. But then, if a container is the same as a hdd, i wonder if i should also not use more than 75% to 80% of the capacity of the container?, wich would mean 80% of  a container the size of 80% of the size of my hdd (100 GB), 100GB x 80% (80 GB) x 80% = 64GB, i loose 33% of the capacity of the hdd, but it looks like the safest way